# Meta Data and title do not update, fetching data from backend in Angular-v6 Universal project

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I setup a Angular CLI -v6.0.0 project and rendered from server side using this link [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal). My entire project is successfully rendering from server side. Demo link is here [MyUniversalDemo](http://118.179.223.38:8081/).

When I click on the product to go to the product detail page, title and meta info are updating and I found it in source view as my expectation when I use static data.

But problem is when I am trying to update title and meta info by fetching data from backend using a http request, title and meta info are not updating.

My SEO content update service :

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class SeoContentLoaderService {

constructor(private titleService: Title, private metaService: Meta) { }

setContent(title: string, description: string, keywords: string, slug: string = '', image: string = '', update = true) {
            let tags = {
                title: title && title != '' && update ? title : "Boibazar Largest Online Book Store in Bangladesh",
                description: description && description != '' && update ? description : "Buy Books & Get Home Delivery anywhere in Bangladesh",
                keywords: keywords && keywords != '' && update ? keywords : "Books, Boibazar, Boimela, Book, Bangladesh, Largest, Big, Boro, Bishal, Online, Shop, Place",
                image: image
            }

            this.titleService.setTitle(tags.title);

            this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:card', content: 'Product' });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:site', content: 'Boibazar.com' });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: tags.title });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: tags.description });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:image', content: `http://118.179.223.38:8081/${tags.image}` });

            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'Product' });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'Boibazar.com' });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: tags.title });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: tags.description });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: `http://118.179.223.38:8081/${tags.image}` });
            this.metaService.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: `http://118.179.223.38:8081/book/${slug}` });
        }
    }
```

And the product detail component:

```
    import { Component, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { ProductService, SeoContentLoaderService } from'../shared/services';

         @Component({
            selector: 'product-detail',
            templateUrl: './product.details.html',
            styleUrls: ['./product.details.scss'],
            encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
        })

    export class ProductDetailComponent {
        public product: any = {};
        constructor(
                  private seoContentLoaderService: SeoContentLoaderService,
                  private route: ActivatedRoute,
                  public productService: ProductService){}

        ngOnInit() {
         let slug=this.route.snapshot.params['slug'];
         this.productService.get(slug).subscribe((result) => {
           this.product = result.product;
           this.seoContentLoaderService.setContent(
           this.product.name, this.product.meta_tag_description, 
           this.product.meta_tag_keywords, slug, this.product.image
           );
        })
       }
```

Comment: what type of database are you using?

Comment: Did you add console logs to make sure that it does go through the code, with the correct values when doing rendering server side?

Comment: @sugarme I am using MongoDB, ExpressJS in server side.

Comment: @David Yes, I console and got my title and metadata when I inspect code in browser and title which I added also appear in title bar,But not in source view.

Comment: Your site is getting errors for API requests, are you sure the API is working fine server-side?

Comment: No, There have no error in server side. I think the issue will be solved with state transfer. See this link.
 
https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c

@Joshua Chan

Comment: Hi Shamim, Have you fixed this error..? I have stuck with same in the implementation of https://mypleaks.com/#/ ..? Can you suggest me something.

Comment: No I can't. I have migrated my application angular to php. Since SEO was very big issue in my case.